# MySQL JOIN ON vs USING

Tags: mysql, sql

En MySQL JOIN, ¿cuál es la diferencia entre `ON` y `USING ()` ?

Por lo que puedo decir, `USING()` es una sintaxis más conveniente, mientras que `ON` permite un poco más de flexibilidad cuando los nombres de columna no son idénticos. Sin embargo, esa diferencia es tan pequeña que pensarías que simplemente eliminarían `USING ()`.

¿Hay más en esto de lo que parece? En caso afirmativo, ¿qué debería usar en una situación dada?

---

#### Referencia:

- [Pregunta orignal SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366006/mysql-on-vs-using)

Comment: Me llamo la atención que esta pregunta/respuesta no estuviese ya en SOes. Siéntanse libres de agregar lo que consideren que falte en la respuesta ya que es `wiki de comunidad`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es principalmente azúcar sintáctico, pero hay un par de diferencias notables:

### `ON`

Es el más general de los dos. Uno puede unir tablas `ON` **una columna, un conjunto de columnas e incluso una condición**.
Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM world.City JOIN world.Country ON (City.CountryCode = Country.Code) WHERE ...
```

### `USING`

Ees útil cuando **ambas tablas comparten una columna del mismo nombre exacto en el que se unen**.
Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT ... FROM film JOIN film_actor USING (film_id) WHERE ...
```

---

Un buen adicional es que uno no necesita calificar completamente las columnas de unión:

```
SELECT film.title, film_id -- film_id is not prefixed
FROM film
JOIN film_actor USING (film_id)
WHERE ...
```

Para ilustrar, para hacer lo anterior con ON, tendríamos que escribir:

```
SELECT film.title, film.film_id -- film.film_id is required here
FROM film
JOIN film_actor ON (film.film_id = film_actor.film_id)
WHERE ...
```

Observese la calificación `film.film_id` en la cláusula `SELECT`. Sería inválido simplemente decir `film_id` ya que eso crearía una ambigüedad:

> ERROR 1052 (23000): Column 'film_id' in field list is ambiguous

En cuanto a `SELECT *`, la columna de unión aparece en el conjunto de resultados dos veces con `ON` mientras que solo aparece una vez con `USING`:

```
mysql> create table t(i int);insert t select 1;create table t2 select*from t;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.11 sec)

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.19 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select*from t join t2 on t.i=t2.i;
+------+------+
| i    | i    |
+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |
+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select*from t join t2 using(i);
+------+
| i    |
+------+
|    1 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

---

#### Referencia:

- [Respuesta original SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11367066/3791844)

Comment: Que buena aclaración @Marcos